# How to convert number to words?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there any formula / procedure to convert number to words. e.g 25371.34 to be converted as "Twenty Five Thousand Three Hundred Seventy One and paise Thirty Four Only".

Comment: What do you mean by **paise**?

Comment: Indian currency is in Rupees & paises. Just like US $ is in terms of Dollar & cents.

Comment: Few syntax errors had to be taken care of like         Do While MyNumber <> ""  AND             If Temp <> "" Then
                Rupees = Temp & Place(Count) & Rupees
            End If Otherwise it works fine. Also had to customize for INR. But thanks any way 'cause it gave me a starting point to work on.

Comment: Except for few syntex errors it works fine. need to fine tune for Indian environment as currency is not in millions, billions etc but thousand, lacs, crores etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to convert a numeric value into English words in Excel

> This article contains sample Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications
>   functions that you can use to convert a numeric value in a Microsoft
>   Excel worksheet cell into its equivalent in English words.
>
> How to create the sample function Called SpellNumber
>
> 1. Start Microsoft Excel.
> 2. Press ALT+F11 to start the Visual Basic Editor.
> 3. On the Insert menu, click Module.
> 4. Type the following code into the module sheet.

```
Option Explicit
'Main Function
Function SpellNumber(ByVal MyNumber)
    Dim Dollars, Cents, Temp
    Dim DecimalPlace, Count
    ReDim Place(9) As String
    Place(2) = " Thousand "
    Place(3) = " Million "
    Place(4) = " Billion "
    Place(5) = " Trillion "
    ' String representation of amount.
    MyNumber = Trim(Str(MyNumber))
    ' Position of decimal place 0 if none.
    DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")
    ' Convert cents and set MyNumber to dollar amount.
    If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
        Cents = GetTens(Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & _
                  "00", 2))
        MyNumber = Trim(Left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))
    End If
    Count = 1
    Do While MyNumber <> ""
        Temp = GetHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3))
        If Temp <> "" Then Dollars = Temp & Place(Count) & Dollars
        If Len(MyNumber) > 3 Then
            MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)
        Else
            MyNumber = ""
        End If
        Count = Count + 1
    Loop
    Select Case Dollars
        Case ""
            Dollars = "No Dollars"
        Case "One"
            Dollars = "One Dollar"
         Case Else
            Dollars = Dollars & " Dollars"
    End Select
    Select Case Cents
        Case ""
            Cents = " and No Cents"
        Case "One"
            Cents = " and One Cent"
              Case Else
            Cents = " and " & Cents & " Cents"
    End Select
    SpellNumber = Dollars & Cents
End Function

' Converts a number from 100-999 into text 
Function GetHundreds(ByVal MyNumber)
    Dim Result As String
    If Val(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function
    MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)
    ' Convert the hundreds place.
    If Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1) <> "0" Then
        Result = GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1)) & " Hundred "
    End If
    ' Convert the tens and ones place.
    If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
        Result = Result & GetTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2))
    Else
        Result = Result & GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))
    End If
    GetHundreds = Result
End Function

' Converts a number from 10 to 99 into text. 
Function GetTens(TensText)
    Dim Result As String
    Result = ""           ' Null out the temporary function value.
    If Val(Left(TensText, 1)) = 1 Then   ' If value between 10-19...
        Select Case Val(TensText)
            Case 10: Result = "Ten"
            Case 11: Result = "Eleven"
            Case 12: Result = "Twelve"
            Case 13: Result = "Thirteen"
            Case 14: Result = "Fourteen"
            Case 15: Result = "Fifteen"
            Case 16: Result = "Sixteen"
            Case 17: Result = "Seventeen"
            Case 18: Result = "Eighteen"
            Case 19: Result = "Nineteen"
            Case Else
        End Select
    Else                                 ' If value between 20-99...
        Select Case Val(Left(TensText, 1))
            Case 2: Result = "Twenty "
            Case 3: Result = "Thirty "
            Case 4: Result = "Forty "
            Case 5: Result = "Fifty "
            Case 6: Result = "Sixty "
            Case 7: Result = "Seventy "
            Case 8: Result = "Eighty "
            Case 9: Result = "Ninety "
            Case Else
        End Select
        Result = Result & GetDigit _
            (Right(TensText, 1))  ' Retrieve ones place.
    End If
    GetTens = Result
End Function

' Converts a number from 1 to 9 into text. 
Function GetDigit(Digit)
    Select Case Val(Digit)
        Case 1: GetDigit = "One"
        Case 2: GetDigit = "Two"
        Case 3: GetDigit = "Three"
        Case 4: GetDigit = "Four"
        Case 5: GetDigit = "Five"
        Case 6: GetDigit = "Six"
        Case 7: GetDigit = "Seven"
        Case 8: GetDigit = "Eight"
        Case 9: GetDigit = "Nine"
        Case Else: GetDigit = ""
    End Select
End Function
```

The rest of the article linked to explains how to use the above function.

**You will have to change the functions to add `paise` to "and" and to append `only`**

Source [How to convert a numeric value into English words in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213360)